# Change font format with xlwings on Mac and get an AttributeError

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwings

I have simple table in an Excel file called Book1.xlsx
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTE7Q.png)

I was trying to get the font information of cell 'A1' with xlwings, code like below

```
app = App(visible = False, add_book = False)
wb = app.books.open('Book1.xlsx')
sht = wb.sheets[0]
rng = sht.range('A1')
font_name = rng.api.Font.Name
font_color = rng.api.Font.ColorIndex
font_size = rng.api.Font.Size
print(font_name, font_color, font_size)
```

By running this, I got an AttributeError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aeosa/appscript/reference.py in 
__getattr__(self, name)
    574                 try:
--> 575                         selectortype, code = self.AS_appdata.referencebyname()[name]
    576                 except KeyError as e:

KeyError: 'Font'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-265d904476e5> in <module>
----> 1 font_color = rng.api.Font.ColorIndex
      2 font_name = rng.api.Font.Name
      3 font_size = rng.api.Font.Size

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aeosa/appscript/reference.py in     
__getattr__(self, name)
    575                         selectortype, code = self.AS_appdata.referencebyname()[name]
    576                 except KeyError as e:
--> 577                         raise AttributeError("Unknown property, element or command: 
{!r}".format(name)) from e
    578                 if selectortype == kProperty:
    579                         return Reference(self.AS_appdata, 
self.AS_aemreference.property(code))

AttributeError: Unknown property, element or command: 'Font'
```

However, I could perfectly run this code on Windows 10. Why it doesn't work well on Mac?

Answer (score 1):

```
print(sht.range('A1').api.font_object.properties.get())
```

Using this, you will get the correct way to write xlwings font API in Mac OS X

Comment: How to use these properties to write in future ( say the whole row which we write from Python to excel)